# Функция strtotime и переменные

Tags: php, переменные

Доброго времени суток !

Сразу извиняюсь если что то неправильно называю. 

Работаю с API ВКонтакте и там есть метод `wall.post` и в нем есть параметр `publish_date`(дата публикации поста, грубо говоря таймер отправки поста). 

Я делаю запрос для отправки поста и использую этот параметр.

И вместо простого использования `unixtime`, как требует того ВК, Я использую функцию `strtotime`, когда строю PHP запрос. 


Как мне правильно составить `strtotime`, чтобы переменная `$view_timePublish['timePublish']` работала ?


Пробовал менять кавычки, все равно API ВК игнорирует параметр `publish_date`. 

К этой переменной присваивается значение из базы данных. 

Вот код:

```
$date_posting = strtotime('+'.$view_timePublish['timePublish'].' min');

$request_params_group = array(

    'owner_id' => $group_ids,
    'from_group' => 1,
    'message' => $post_message,
    'attachments' => $ready_photo,
    'publish_date' => $date_posting,
    'access_token' => $access_token_standalone,
    'v' => $api_version

);
$get_params_group = http_build_query($request_params_group);
$result_group = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?'. $get_params_group));
```

Comment: Проверил сразу 
`$min = 11;
 $date_posting = strtotime('+'.$min.' min');
 echo date("d.M.Y h:i",$date_posting);`

Всё верно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в чем была ошибка.
Ошибка заключалась в том что надо было прогнать то время которое берется из БД еще раз через strtotime();

```
$expire_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+".$view_timePublish['timePublish']." min"));
$date_posting = strtotime($expire_stamp);
```

Comment: Но зачем? Уберите date, там уже timestamp